# Twitter Gem with multiple search options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I cant figure this out. This works:

```
@client.search("#{term}", :result_type => "recent")
```

This does not work

```
@client.search("#{term}", :result_type => "recent", :geocode => "#{lat},#{long},#{radius}mi")
```

It seems that adding the :geocode parameter broke it, however it renders perfectly to what the example is on the [the twitter api docs.](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm an idiot. The code examples both work.

But let this serve as a warning to others... it's easier to get 0 tweets returned than you'd think. A 1 mile radius is pretty small even for common search terms. Try 10000 miles to be sure your geocode works, then compare to 1 mile.